# Integrate GNU Gatekeeper with Freeswitch..?

Tags: freeswitch, h.323, opalvoip

I try to make h323 calls using opal & mod_h323 on free-switch but calls not happen ?

So i am trying to use external gatekeeper to calls h323 but i want route calls through free-switch ?

please any buddy guide how can establish the h323 calls using external gatekeeper or any other solution for free-switch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register just like a regular endpoint using the [[Endpoint]](http://www.gnugk.org/gnugk-manual-12.html#ss12.5) config section of the GNU Gatekeeper. GnuGk would call Freeswitch a "parent" then.

Or you can configure Freeswitch as a [permanent endpoint](http://www.gnugk.org/gnugk-manual-7.html#ss7.3) in GnuGk and configure the IP of GnuGk in Freeswitch as a peer.

Comment: please give a process how to configure...because before i am taken reference from Gnugk site but not successes,please send details about that on site or my email (vishal.s1504@gmail.com).